# Need help understanding difference in raw image binary data for PHPUnit test

Tags: php, string, imagemagick, compare, phpunit

So I wrote a Unit Test to compare cropped images (using imagemagick) in PHP. The test works, but i've been running into problems when it comes to comparing a large number of images at a time. Depending on the time the image is created at, each image receives a timestamp that is embedded directly into the raw data. I've been using a regular expression to pull out that timestamp right before comparing the files but it appears as though every once in a while, one of the image files will have additional raw data in it even though they're exactly the same.

To give an example, here's the result from one of my tests (note, i'm comparing the binary data of the images as a string):

> ImageTest::testAutoCrop
>
> Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
>
> --- Expected
>
> +++ Actual
>
> @@ @@
>
> ?n??m?
>
> -?F sO=f??????????^???????w??>
>
> ```
>                           ?(???/o????M)???o%tEXt??%tEXt
> ```
>
> +?F sO=f??????????^???????w??>
>
> ```
>                           ?(???/o????M)???o%tEXt
> ```

As you can see....the only difference between these two files is that the expected image has this additional string in it: "?%tEXt".

Can someone help me understand what this random piece of data represents? That will help me figure out how to modify my unit test so that issues like this won't happen anymore.

Thanks,

Malcolm

PS: Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: What imagemagick API? What image format? (Imagemagick has a "-strip" option but it does not seem to work with PNG.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I eventually came up with a solution to this issue. Couple things to clarify:

1. The reason why I was making unit tests is because our imageservice web application ( PHP ) uses Imagemagick to handle all image processing, manipulation , conversion of HTML to image, and PDF to image ( jpg,png,gif, all non cmyk, pdf ) conversions that happen on our main website. Needed to make sure that as we added new features to this image service application, there were enough tests in place to ensure that everything still functioned correctly.
2. The string data that we saw in each image ( aka: ?%tEXt ) is the image's exif data. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format ) in order to compare pictures ( suggestion taken from David Andersson's reply ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/904933/david-andersson ) we needed to completely strip all comment data out of the image along with the creation date time stamp / modified on info. That way you're dealing with simply an image and no other type of meta data. We did that with the following function:

```
protected static function _removeTimeStamp( $string, $pdf = false ) {

  /* Note: Assume $string parameter is the image you're planning on cleaning in string format. */

  /* If you're working with a pdf, you need to remove the CreationDate using regex from the string representation. */
  if ( $pdf )
    return preg_replace( '/(CreationDate[^)]+)/', '', $string );

  /* Create a path for the temporary image we're going to need to create that will hold the exif free image */
  $strip_tmp = 'test/strip_tmp';

  /* write contents of string to temp string file */
  file_put_contents( $strip_tmp, $string );

  /* this will remove all exif data along with the date:create and date:modify properties from the image */
  exec( 'convert ' . $strip_tmp . ' -strip +set date:create +set date:modify ' . $strip_tmp . ' 2> /dev/null' ); 

  /* get the string representation of the new "cleaned" image */
  $result = file_get_contents( $strip_tmp ); 

  /* delete the temp file */
  unlink( $strip_tmp ); 

  /* return the cleaned string */
  return $result;

} // _removeTimeStamp
```

This was run on each image before comparing them to each other ( in String format ). Hopefully this helps someone in the future who might be doing something similar.

I plan on writing a blog post about this in more detail to show how I took care of a number of other tests. When I do I will update this question with the link in either the comments or this answer. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: OMG! String comparison of binary data in PHP... Gotta know your stuff, eh?  Wouldn't it be much more efficient to  (1) strip your meta data differences  (2) create an md5sum of the data and then (3) compare the two md5sums ?!?

Comment: Kurt, that could definitely work as well and would probably be a lot more efficient. Only reason I didn't do that off the bat was for debugging purposes. When the unit tests failed, it was nice to look at the actual data inside to see if anything was wrong OR to actually view the image and see if it was rendered correctly. If you create an md5sum might be a little bit more difficult to debug if there is an issue. Perhaps a flag to enable that and disable it when needed would be appropriate.

Comment: If a unit test fails you'll have to debug in any case... Unit tests are meant to be fast and repeated very often (and are expected to be 'green' in 99% or more of test runs once your code started to work at all...  Or are you doing this in a TDD environment?)

Comment: No you're right, unit tests are definitely meant to be fast and repeated often, so I think you're suggestion makes complete sense ( especially now that we've fully created all of the unit tests and we've confirmed that they're accurate etc). My suggestion was to add a flag to enable debug mode and not create an md5sum of each piece of data if something fails and you need to dig deeper. But having the default flag set to create md5sums would certainly be more efficient. Might make that change with our next iteration of our application.

Answer (score 1):

In unit tests you should only test your units, not third party code's units.

You have not specified any details about your image resizer, but I assume you're making use of third-party functions which count as units of their own (one function is a unit, like one class is a unit).

So the question would be: Is the binary data generated by your code, your units? I guess not, otherwise you would have known why the binary data differs.

As those aren't your units, don't write tests for them. Instead, go to the project the original units come from (upstream) and check for their test-suite instead.

If you're concerned for integration tests (test that different units work with each other), you should define stable tests that can deal with the (different) data returned by sub-components. E.g. you might need an image comparison (is the pixel size and are the pixel values (as well as the fileformat maybe) correct) instead of comparing binary data which can differ as file-formats often allow more than one way how to encode the same image data (plus meta data).

Comment: And mock it so hat you don't have to deal with it's intricacies